# Entity Framework generated SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have an 2 EF entity defined as:

```
public class Event
{               
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Public { get; set; }
    public EventType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }              
}

public class Note
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }      // Link to parent event
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

When accessing the `Notes` collection in `Event`, a SQL query is constructed in the form:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text]
    FROM [dbo].[Notes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[EventId] = @EntityKeyValue1',
    N'@EntityKeyValue1 nvarchar(128)',
    @EntityKeyValue1=N'N5427961'
```

This query, given the data size and indexing used required in excess of 3000 reads. This seemed a bit much given the tables have sufficient indexing. Query analyser had no suggestions to speed the query up.

I then discovered if I changed the datatype being used in the SQL bind from `nvarchar(128)` to `varchar(33)`, which matches exactly the column type of `EventId` in the DB table, the query now only needed 8 reads.

Is this simply a case of me needing to use DataAnnotations to tell EF what the data types in SQL these fields are? or is something else happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to most easily get the desired effect was:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().Property(x => x.Id).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(33);
```

The other suggested method using annotation did not work and resulted in `nvarchar` still being used.